# How to make a shell command persist when running from vim

Tags: vim, hotkeys

I've got a script I made mapped to a key in vim.

It runs fine, except that immediately after, vim terminates the shell, and that's what causes the script to not work right.

How can I get this to work right?

Comment: How does terminating the shell keep the script from working correctly?  We need more details.

Answer (score 2):

map your script using `:!nohup COMMAND &` and it should work. This will create a nohup.out file with any output from the command

Comment: You should be able to get rid of `nohup.out` by redirecting to `/dev/null`.